# Issues with saving XML file (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, save

I'm trying to make a config file from an XML file, but I can't figure out how to save the file after I add to it. I can read from the file fine, so I know it's not an issue with where it's located, but I still don't know how to save it.

I've looked around for about 2 hours and can't figure out the problem. I'm know my way around c# but am completely new to XML.

```
public async Task CreateReaction(string name, DiscordMessage message, DiscordEmoji emoji, DiscordRole role)
{
    string path = @"E:\Visual Studio\repos\JustHangoutBot\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\configs\reactions.xml";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

    await message.CreateReactionAsync(emoji);

    XElement root = new XElement(name);
    root.Add(new XElement("MessageID", message.Id));
    root.Add(new XElement("ReactionID", emoji.Id));
    root.Add(new XElement("RoleID", role.Id));
    doc.Element("Reactions").Add(root);

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    doc.Save(stream);
}
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the last three lines. I've seen tutorials of people saving the file by just using `doc.Save("reactions.xml")` for example, but I get the error of not being able to  convert from string to Stream.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know what this line is doing? "Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path);"  It is taking the path string and converting to bytes (not the xml data).  The code doc.Save("reactions.xml") should work using a string for the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("path to the file you want to write"))
{
    doc.Save(fileStream);
}
```

When you do this:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
doc.Save(stream);
```

What's happening is

- You're opening the file at `path` and reading it into a byte array.
- You're creating a `MemoryStream` that has those bytes as its content
- You're saving that document to the `MemoryStream`.

Under the hood a `MemoryStream` is just an array of bytes in memory. So it's writing the file to memory, not to a file.

[`File.OpenWrite(path)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite) opens a `FileStream` with the specified path. If the file doesn't exist it creates it. If the file does exist it will overwrite it.

So when you call `doc.Save(fileStream)` you're writing to the file.